# jquery toggle animate

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, toggle

I have this situation:

```
$("#button").toggle(function(){
    $("#window").animate({top:'0%'},1000);
},function(){
    $("#window").animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
});
```

but I need change it to work with `.click` event, like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
```

if `#window` position is `top:'0%'`, animate to `top:'-100%'`

if `#window` position is `top:-100%'`, animate to `top:'0%'`

and when the user clicks multiple times on the `#button` does not get the animation to repeat itself

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SHOULD work!!

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
     if($("#window").css('top') == '0%'){
       $("#window").stop().animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
     };
     if($("#window").css('top') == '-100%'){
        $("#window").stop().animate({top:'0%'},1000);
     };
 });
```

Make sure your css has this:

```
​#window{
   position: absolute;
   top:0%;   /* -100% as the default case may be */
}​
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dNPWg/
Click on the red bar for animation (change the -100% to 100% for better understanding of whether .stop() is working or not)

Comment: I believe this works, except comparing the strings. Isn't that done in js with '==='?

Comment: well in fact i tried the comparison part in fiddle, (alerting instead of animating). Worked fine. @LGVentura Try placing an alert in the if conditions in stead of animate and add this $("#window").css('top','-100%'); and $("#window").css('top','0%'); appropriately. Will atleast come to know whether the if condtions are working or not

Comment: but does not work in Firefox. only in Safari and Chrome. is there any alternative way?

Comment: oh! Sorry mate, dunno too much about jQuery and browser compatibilities. Will search a bit and get back if I find something...till then try replacing animate function with  $("#window").css('top','-100%'); or if it still doesn't work, remove the iff conditions and check

Answer (score 1):

This code should work...

```
var i = 0;
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    if(i == 0) {
        $("#window").stop().animate({top:'0%'},1000);
        i = 1;
    } else {
        $("#window").stop().animate({top:'-100%'},1000);
        i = 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: Remember to stop the animation queue by using `.stop()` -- `$(window).stop().animate(...`

Comment: perhaps a boolean is better suited here?